# by using maven Build projects and deploy it using jboss-maven-plugin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven-2, jboss

I have 2 (`core`, `core-web`) projects such a way that one is depending on another.

so the `core-web`'s POM.xml contains the dependency of `core`.

`core-web` will be deployed on jBoss AS (5.1). Therefore want to use `jboss-maven-plugin`

I have to run install on both `core` and `core-web` after every change and have to deploy the file manually. Everything is seems to be working fine if I put the `war` file to the `deploy`.

Just want to ask that if there is a way that I can make a routine in core-web's POM that it automatically generates `core.jar` and `core-web.war` and deploy it to the running jboss server on `localhost:8080` port.

Please let me know if there is more information you require.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the issue. I made another `pom.xml` and and added `core` and `core-web` in the module tag and now I have to install this new `pom` and it installs all the dependent `pom`s in a sequential way.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
    <artifactId>build-all</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>build-all</name>
        <parent>
        .......
    </parent>
        <modules>
        <module>..</module>
        <module>../core</module>
        <module>../model</module>
        <module>../cas-server</module>
        <module>../core-web</module>
        <module>../other-projects</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```